# Equality in distribution uniquely determines a matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ be a continuous stochastic process in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $A, B\in\mathrm{GL}_d(\mathbb{R})$ two invertible linear maps. Let further $AX:=(AX_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$.

Do you know of any 'nice' sufficient condition on the law of $X$ to conclude that

$$AX \stackrel{d}{=} BX \quad \Longrightarrow \quad A = B \ ?$$

Any hints or references are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

Take $U_t\sim \mathcal N(0,t)$ and $X_t=(U_t,U_t)$ for all $t$. Then, what about taking
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\quad \text{and}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: What is unclear in this counter-example ?

Comment: Why is it that $AX\stackrel{d}{=} BX$ for every continuous stochastic process $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @rmcerafl: I edited my answer. But you obviously don't have $AX=BX$ for all continuous $X$...

Comment: Thanks, @Surb. I know that the above doesn't work for every process (e.g. your conterexample, or just constant processes etc), which is why the question was on *sufficient conditions* for $\mathbb{P}_X$ for which the identifiability holds :)